# Joomla Site Offline message & logo not appearing?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Just after installing a fresh version of Joomla 3.2.2 with all the normal configuration.

When I put the site into offline mode, in the frontend I get "The service is unavailable" instead of the Offline Message & Offline Image.

Why does this happen? I have noticed on other instillation's too that I never get to see the offline message and login box, just a white page with "The service is unavailable".

How can I fix this?  Can't find any support on it :(

Comment: do you have any special template installed, or any other quickstart package ?

Comment: IIS or Apache? What host? (My guess is Windows on GoDaddy.)

Comment: Using IIS7. No sample data or anything installed on my new site. I'm a blacknight.com customer. If I install through their application vault OR install a standalone Joomla instillation I get the same result.  It works for me on Joomla 1.5, but it doesn't work on 1.7, 2.5 and 3.2. Could it be a file permission problem?

Comment: Does your template have an offline.php file?

Comment: No it doesn't have offline.php.  Is it needed? Is that not just for a custom offline template? None of the default templates have this either.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the offline.php exists, it is found in /templates/system directory
also check file permissions on this directory to ensure public has access.

Offline files that exist under the template directory will override the system one.